# If statement error !=

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have this macro:

```
Sub fixComma()
'
' fixComma Macro
'
'
'  If (Selection.Start != Selection.End) Then
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "([0-9]).([0-9])"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1,\2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   '  Else
     '  MsgBox "Nothing is selected, Macro terminated"
  '  End If
End Sub
```

If I uncomment the if-else statements I get the following error:

```
Compile Error:
type declaration character does not match declared data type
```

The macro was recorded and I added the if statement to prevent the user from applying it without selecting text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you confusing VBA syntax with another language like javascript? VBA uses `<>` as a not-equal-to operator. The `!=` is used by javascript and some other C-style languages.

```
If Selection.Start <> Selection.End Then
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is working but not really the way I want. it is replacing in all instead of just the selected text, any ideas ? Sorry, I have zero experience with VBA

Comment: Sorry, I am not as well versed in Word macros as Excel. I tried to run through your code and even recorded by own version in Word but I cannot get it to stop with the Selection and not continue on through the remainder of the document.

Comment: No worries, Thank you for your help. I will post another question :)

Comment: in case you will find out something later or you are just interested why is that happening , here is the link for my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007089/ms-word-vba-find-and-replace-macro-changing-in-all-the-document-instead-of-jus