# Find and Replace in just the selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following macro. It changes numbers of the form x.x to x,x. It was recorded and I added the IF statement to make sure a text is selected to prevent the user from doing it on the whole document.

```
 Sub fixComma()
    '
    ' fixComma Macro
    '
    '
      If (Selection.Start <> Selection.End) Then
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.LanguageID = wdEnglishUS
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "([0-9]).([0-9])"
            .Replacement.Text = "\1,\2"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchKashida = False
            .MatchDiacritics = False
            .MatchAlefHamza = False
            .MatchControl = False
            .MatchByte = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With

        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
         Else
           MsgBox "Nothing is selected, Macro terminated"
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is it is changing the whole document and not just the selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Changing

```
 Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

to

```
 Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
```

Will get it so the first instance of x.x in a selection will change to x,x and not the whole document.

**Edit:** if you want all items in a selected area only to change then keep:

```
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

But change

```
.Wrap = wdFindAsk
```

to

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

Comment: I want something in between, I want all selection. not all document and not just the first occurrence. it is not worth it to write a macro for the first occurrence ;)

Comment: Sorry, got to test it now only and it seems to be working,Thanks for the help. Good day to you to sir !